# Why User email validation failed? Mongoose ValidationError:

Tags: node.js

I wanted to extend my UserSchema to validate email

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    username: {
      type: String,
    },
    name: {
      type: String,
    },
    email: {
      type: String,
      trim: true,
      required: [true, 'Please add an email'],
      unique: true,
      lowercase: true,
    },
```

I installed [email-validator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/email-validator).

```
userSchema.path('email').validate((email) => {
  if (!validator.validate('email')) { return false; }
  if (!email) { return false; }
  if (email.length === 0) { return false; }
  return true;
}, 'Email must have a valid format!');
```

I made a POST request

```
"username" : "KoleSOmbor",
"name" : "Niki",
"email" : "koprivica@gmail.com",
```

Error

```
POST /api/v1/users 500 18.706 ms - 618
ValidationError: User validation failed: email: Email must have a valid format!
```

Why?

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED

```
if (!validator.validate(email)) { return false; }
```

Works fine.